# passing Image's url from class to another

Tags: netbeans-7

hello Guys. I would like fist to say thanks for all who help us in this greet website.. I am facing problem in passing path of an image  from a frame to another class when user click the button.. the calling is:

```
Filename=txt_attach.getText();
LoadSickLeaveImage sickLeave=new LoadSickLeaveImage();
sickLeave.ImageIcon(Filename);
```

and I want to pass the path for the picture from `txt_attach` into another class to `ImageIcon` method, but nothing shows. No mistake or no errors.

```
public class LoadSickLeaveImage {
    public ImageIcon ImageIcon(String Filename){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Filename);
        return icon;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      LoadSickLeaveImage icon = new LoadSickLeaveImage(); 
      ImageIcon image = icon.ImageIcon("");

      //Check if file exists or not.
      File file = new File(image.toString()); 
      boolean exists = file.exists();
      if (!exists) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the file or directory you are searching does not exist");
      }else{
        JLabel label = new JLabel(); //Make new label where image will be on printed.
        label.setIcon(image);
        JFrame gallery = new JFrame();
        gallery.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        gallery.getContentPane().add(label);
        gallery.pack();
        gallery.setLocation(500,450);
        gallery.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: no one want to  help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No need for main method, just provide all stuff in the Constructor in
>   second class. the code==>
>
> import java.io.*; import javax.swing.*; public class
>   LoadSickLeaveImage extends Treatment{
>
> ```
> public LoadSickLeaveImage(String fileName){
>     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(fileName);
>     File file = new File(image.toString());
>     boolean exists = file.exists();
> if (!exists) {    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the file or directory you are searching does not exist");  
> }else{
>   JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
>     label.setIcon(image);
>     JFrame gallery = new JFrame();
>     gallery.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
>     gallery.getContentPane().add(label);
>     gallery.pack();
>     gallery.setLocation(500,450);
>     gallery.setVisible(true);
>
> }
>
> } }
> ```